# Is there a way to fetch artifacts feed packages names and versions to pipeline parameters?

Tags: azure-devops

Im wondering if there is a way to fetch artifacts feed packages names and versions to pipeline parameters, so when i click "run pipeline" I can choose which application and version I want to use in pipeline as variables.
I'd like to automate everything instead of creating new variables with service names and versions, so when new package in feed is added, it is automatically put into the pick list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid this is impossible to achieve this automatically currently. There is no built-in function which can fetch the packages names and versions in azure devops pipeline.

You will need to manually create new pipeline parameters for the newly added packages.

You can also submit a user voice [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion) regarding this feature request.